# How to set the root of git repository to vi/vim find path?

Tags: linux, git, vim

I want to set vim file search path to include git repository root (which can be found by `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`). I can't figure out how to append the output of this `git` command to "`set path=.,,**`" in .vimrc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
let &path .= "," . system("git rev-parse --show-toplevel | tr -d '\\n'")
```

That said, I usually start Vim from the top-level directory of the project and never change the working directory so that's one less setting to worry about.

See `:help system()` and `:help :let`

Comment: That breaks when Vim is not started from a git repository.  It's also less than useful when working with several files from different git repositories at the same time (which is useless by itself, but that's not the point). :)

Comment: @lcd047, all valid points. I kind of assumed the OP already had some logic to find out if he was actually in a git repository.

Comment: Thanks @romainl for this. I wonder if I can use the repo root of the directory where the file I'm opening.

Comment: Also, I used this:
`set path=.,,**  

let &path .= "," . system("git rev-parse --show-toplevel | tr -d '\\n'")`

But I'd like to have "`.,,**`" after the git repo not before.

Comment: This is what I ended up using `let &path .= system("git rev-parse --show-toplevel | tr -d '\\n'") . "/**" . ",./**"`

Answer (score 0):

" Add the git dir only once, and check for errors.

```
function! MoshGitPath()
  let g:gitdir=substitute(system("git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&1 | grep -v fatal:"),'\n','','g')
  if  g:gitdir != '' && isdirectory(g:gitdir) && index(split(&path, ","),g:gitdir) < 0
    exe "set path+=".g:gitdir."/*"
  endif
endfunction
command! MoshGitPath :call MoshGitPath()
:MoshGitPath
```